# Import fulltext then split into truncated and keyword form

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I've hit a bit of a wall and would appreciate some guidance. I want to index a large block of text, like such:

> Several men are in the locker room of a golf club. A cell phone on a
>   bench rings and a man engages the hands-free speaker function and
>   begins to talk. Everyone else in the room stops to listen. The man
>   hangs up. The other men in the locker room are looking at him in
>   astonishment. Then he smiles and asks: "Anyone know whose phone
>   is???!!!"

*I dont want to store this fulltext as it is in Solr*, I want to instead have two versions of it. One as a truncated form, and one as a keyword form.

**Truncated Form:**

> Several men are in the locker room of a golf club. A cell phone on a
>   bench rings and a man engages the hands-free speaker function and
>   begins to talk. Everyone else...

**Keyword Form (using stopwords to remove common words):**

> Several men locker room golf club cell phone bench rings man engages
>   hands-free speaker function begins talk Everyone else room stops
>   listen man hangs up other men locker room looking him astonishment
>   smiles asks Anyone know whose phone

How should I be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform these transformations on client side and then have two fields in Solr for each version.